# Get prefix before key in db

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So im using replits database system and i have a command where `if message.content.lower() in db.keys` then if will respond with the value of the key.

for example

[image]

but i want it so that it has to have "$" in front so $fff

```
if message.content.lower() in db.keys()':
        info = db[f'{message.content.lower()}']
        await message.channel.send(f'{info}')
```

above is my code, ive tryed also:

```
if message.content.lower() in f'${db.keys()}':
        info = db[f'{message.content.lower()}']
        await message.channel.send(f'{info}')
```

and:

```
if message.content.lower() == f'${db.keys()}':
        info = db[f'{message.content.lower()}']
        await message.channel.send(f'{info}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from what you tried with your sample implementations it looks to me as if you're looking for something like this [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```
if message.content.lower() in [f'${k}' for k in db.keys()]:
    info = db[message.content.lower()[1:]]
    await message.channel.send(f'{info}')
```

But in terms of readability and simplicity I have to agree with Lukas Kwiecinski's answer.
Just add a check before if the message.content starts with '$' as you want it to.

```
if message.content.startswith('$'):
    key = message.content[1:].lower()
    if key in db.keys():
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply slice the string,

```py
if message.content.lower()[1:] in db.keys():
    ...
```

Or a cleaner way

```py
q = message.content[1:].lower()
if q in db.keys():
    ...
```